# jQuery select values as list

Tags: jquery, struts2, fullcalendar

I am building a calendar within my struts2 application using [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/).  But... I am running into a bit of a problem.  We have built an advanced search that allows us to filter the calendar events server side and return a result list.  I am able to get most everything to work correctly with the exception of a select with multiple and I think it is because I am using my jquery wrong.

My `ajaxLocationCalendar.action` is expecting to see a list of locations and not a string with multiple locations.

Within my code I have a `<select id="locationsSelect" multiple="multiple">` which has several options.

My fullcalendar setup looks like the following:

```
events: {
  url: 'ajaxLocationCalendar.action',
  data: {
    'scheduleableCriteria.approvalStatus': function() {
      return $('#approvalStatusSelect').val();
    },
    'scheduleableCriteria.locations': function() {
      return $('#locationsSelect').val();
    }
  }
}
```

The `#approvalStatusSelect` works perfectly because there are 4 valid options and it is a single select.  However I am having problems with the `#locationSelect`.

If I select nothing I end up sending `"null"` which is not a match to anything.  If I select exactly one option I get a valid result because it is wrapped up correctly.  If I try to send two selected I end up sending something like `"Apartment,Building+3"`.

Is there a function other than `.val()` that would allow me to send a list rather than what I am getting now?

Any help appreciated, if you need clarification put it in the comments and I will try to clarify more.

Comment: You probably want to [take a look at map()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5794756/1654265)

Comment: @AndreaLigios unfortunately I am not quite sure how that can solve my problem :-(  True I can build a key value pair that way but... Its not quite right.  $.map() I end up with something like the following: `0[name]: "scheduableCriteria.locations"` `0[value]: "Apartment"` `1[name]: "scheduableCriteria.locations"` `1[value]: "Gym"`   But what I need is    `scheduableCriteria.locations : Apartment` `scheduableCriteria.locations : Gym`

Comment: Struts translates multiple of the same Name into a `List` and each instance as a an entry.  Using the map I would have to iterate over the items within my `Java action` and do some funky behind the scenes stuff.

Comment: Just declare your `scheduleableCriteria.locations` as a list.

Comment: @AleksandrM within my action I have a `ScheduleableCritera` and within that I have `private List<String> locations;`  So... it is already a `List`.  But, as I said in the  question multiple options being selected results in a string similar to this: `"scheduableCriteria.locations":"Apartment, Gym"`  rather than two entry's  `scheduableCriteria.locations : Apartment` `scheduableCriteria.locations : Gym`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following ended up using the following as .serialize() and .seralizeArray() did not work properly.

```
data: function() {
  var data = {};
  data['scheduleableCriteria.approvalStatus'] = $("#approvalStatusSelect").val();
  var locations = $("#locationsSelect").val();
  if (locations) {
    $.each(locations, function(i, location) {
      data['scheduleableCriteria.locations[' + i + ']'] = location;
    });
  }
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'scheduleableCriteria.locations': function() {
      return $('#locationsSelect').val();
    }
```

This will only return a String - showing multiple values as comma-separated list. So in the action they actually end up being a single-string.

Put all the fields to submit in a form-tag and then use serialization as below

`var submit_data = $('form').serialize();`

Your code will then change to appear something as :

```
events: {
  url: 'ajaxLocationCalendar.action',
  data: submit_data        
}
```

This way the multi-select will be submitted as an array instead of a string.

**Solution 2 :**

To create a custom-function, to parse the select and return you an array of all selected values

[Complete Solution Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11421904/send-multiple-select-elements-with-jquery-post)

Comment: Sadly this did not work due to the way data was sent over.  I do not remember the particulars of what went wrong but it seems that using the .serialize() ended up doing a k,v with only one character per key, value.  Thank you for your help attempt.